# Can JQuery UI tooltips be used with a CFLayoutArea?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, extjs, coldfusion, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am attempting to add JQuery UI tooltips into content within a CFLayout.  However, in IE8 (quirks mode) the tooltip is appearing against the left margin of the browser.  I believe this is some sort of incompatibility between JQuery and Ext-JS.

To test I tried creating an absolutely positioned div with a left of 200px within the `<CFLayoutArea` to see if it would also stick to the left of the browser, but it did not.  Instead, it appeared 200px from the left side of the `<CFLayoutArea` whereas it should have appeared at 200px from the left side of the browser window.

Has anyone run into and resolved a similar issue?  Switching out of quirks mode is not an option at this point.

**UPDATE**

I've managed a hack by using code like this:

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    updateTooltipPositions();
}



function updateTooltipPositions() {
    $("[id^='ui-tooltip-']").css("left", mouseX-401);
    $("[id^='ui-tooltip-']").css("top", mouseY+1);
}
```

However, it's not a clean solution, and it prevents the animation when tooltips are showing.

Comment: The problem is probably with `cflayout`. The UI stuff in ColdFusion is dreadful. Do yourself a favor and rip it out and use the JS library of your choice, like jQuery or ExtJS.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option here.  I need to find a workaround for the time being.

Comment: What version of CF are you using?

Comment: Doing it the right way is not an option? I feel sorry for you.

Comment: It looks like CF 9 has extjs 3.0 and CF 10 has extjs 3.1. You are going to need to look up how these versions work with what ever version of jquery you have. check to see if any of these apply: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jquery]+[extjs]+tooltip

Comment: @Scott Stroz That seems unnecessarily antagonistic.  The majority of large corporations will not okay a huge project changing tens of thousands of lines of code across hundreds of pages without a very clear RoI that management fully buys into.  Even then, the developer time may just not be there.

Comment: @James Mohler Thank you for the suggestion.  We are using CF9.  I'll search through the link you provided and see if anything seems related to what we're experiencing.

Comment: It was not meant to be antagonistic, it was meant to be empathetic. It sucks that the company does not see the benefit in doing things the right way. I would hate to work in that kind of environment again.

Comment: If a company does not see the RoI of doing things the right way, I am not sure that is a company I would want to work for/with. `cflayout` and other UI/AJAX related tags will decrease the RoI of the application when you have to deal with stupid issues like this one.

Comment: When you say you fixed it by 'I've managed a hack by using code like this".. Then that should tell you it is being done the wrong way.

Comment: @ScottStroz I apologize then; I misread your intent.  Unfortunately, traditional managers seem to look more for income than cost savings.  And sometimes the developer time just isn't there without taking them off high priority projects with direct return.

Comment: @DaveFerguson True.  But again, when it's a choice between hacking it in 5 hours or reworking the application in 300 hours, and you have a client waiting on results, your choices are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we decided to use the following hack:

```
 open: function (event, ui) {
     updateTooltipPositions();
 }

 function updateTooltipPositions() {
     $("[id^='ui-tooltip-']").css("left", mouseX-401);
     $("[id^='ui-tooltip-']").css("top", mouseY+1);
 }
```

In addition, IE was giving us some problems with manually closing tooltips.  To avoid that we had to force that particular page out of quirks mode:

```
 <cfheader name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge">   <!--- Force browser into standards mode --->
```

Neither of these are optimal solutions.  However, they worked for our time-sensitive situation.

Comment: We're using it for IE8, though I believe it will force every version of IE into standards mode.  "IE=Edge" should leave Firefox, Chrome, and other browsers alone, in case your page is not fully in compliance (we have some lingering issues).